# A question about Sobolev space and the relationship between the weak convergence on it and the strong convergence on L^p space.

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

Suppose that $\Omega$ is a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is the Sobolev space $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$. If $u_n$ convergent to $u$ weakly in $H_0^1(\Omega)$, can I get the conclusion that $u_n$ convergent to $u$ strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$ and how to prove it? Or we can only get the conclusion with sense of a subsequence?

Thanks a lot for anyone and any help!

Comment: This is the assertion of Rellich's compactness theorem.

Comment: thanks for you answer @gerw, but I can only get from the theorem that there exists a subsequence for the strongly convergence. How about the initial sequence?

Comment: You can use a subsequence-subsequence argument, since the strong limit has to coincide with $u$.

Comment: Thank you sincerely but how to prove $u_n$ is cauchy in $L^2(\Omega)$ to ensure that $u_n$ is convergent? Maybe I don't know the subsequence-subsequence argument. I'm struggling for a long time and I'm sorry for another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $u_n$ does not converge to $u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$.
Then, there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ and a subsequence such that
$$
\|u_{n_k} - u\| \ge \varepsilon \qquad\forall k.$$
By compactness, there exists a further subsequence $u_{n_{k_\ell}}$
with $u_{n_{k_\ell}} \to v$ in $L^2(\Omega)$.
By weak convergence in $H_0^1(\Omega)$, $u = v$.
However, this contradicts the first inequality.

Comment: Hey gerw, sorry to bother you again. I wanna ask you another question. Denote with $H_r^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$ the set of functions in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)=W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^3)$  who are radially symmetric with respect to origin point. I wanna know that whether $H_r^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is a closed set so that it's a reflexive Banach space? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am pretty confident that this is a closed set. It should not be hard to prove since convergence in $H^1$ implies pointwise a.e. convergence of a subsequence.